# Problema al utilitzar contains con una lista

Tags: java

tengo una programa hecho donde voy sumando un contador si la palabra coincide con las que tengo en la lista, Por ejemplo si tengo en una list la palabra [OK,VALE] y estoy mirando una palabra(la frase la corto con un split con un espacio).

En el split no quiero poner una opcion para las comas y puntos, solo quiero un espacio como esta ahora

Esto seria un ejemplo de las palabras que no suman al contador y debería

OK = true

OKEY= false

VALE. = false

VALE, = false

```
private static int contPalabras(String linia, List<String> lista) {

    String[] palabras = linia.split(" ");
    int cont = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
        if (lista.contains(palabras[i].toUpperCase())) {
            cont++;
        }
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Comment: Y no lo van a hacer, porque vos mismo lo estas diciendo, no es lo mismo VALE. que VALE (sin el punto). Tal vez podrias reformular que necesitas?

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres poner otro split puedes quitar las comas y puntos de la palabra antes de comparar.

```
public static String quitarSignos(String palabra) {
        return palabra.replace(",", "").replace(".", "");

    }

    private static int contPalabras(String linia, List<String> lista) {
        linia = quitarSignos(linia);
        String[] palabras = linia.split(" ");
        int cont = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
            if (lista.contains(palabras[i].toUpperCase())) {
                cont++;
            }
        }
        return cont;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas eliminar primero cualquier signo de puntuación que contenga la frase:

```
private static int contPalabras(String linia, List<String> lista){

    String lineaSinSignosDePuntuacion = linia.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ");

    String[] palabras = lineaSinSignosDePuntuacion.split(" ");
    int cont = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
        if (lista.contains(palabras[i].toUpperCase())) {
            cont++;
        }
    }
    return cont;
}
```